# Take json content and store it in another json

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to JSON.  Using ajax call I can get one JSON object. The JSON structure is like this

```
{
    data: [
        {
            bouquet: "Interactive",
            list: []
        },
        {
            bouquet: "Movies",
            list: []
        },
        {
            bouquet: "Music",
            list: []
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

Now I want to store the first five objects into another JSON object.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just a hint: [`array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: I dont know whether it is correct or not but i tried like this. I stored my json in allJson. 
var tempjson="";
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
     tempjson+=allJson.data[i];
}

Comment: I tried to use array.slice(), it is creating the array not the json @Sriko

Comment: Then do a [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) afterwards to serialize your object to JSON.

Answer (score 2):

use the slice() Method

> Definition and Usage
>
> The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new
>   array object.
>
> The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start
>   argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.
>
> Note: The original array will not be changed.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Example:

```
var orgdata = {
    data: [{
        bouquet: "Interactive",
        list: []
    }, {
        bouquet: "Movies",
        list: []
    }, {
        bouquet: "Music",
        list: []
    }]
};
var subdate = orgdata.data.splice(0, 2);

alert(JSON.stringify(subdate));
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/cjGSY/2/

Comment: This is creating the array. How to create it as a json

Comment: var asjson = {data: subdate }

Comment: For example... your question as json is a bit fuzzy ;)